# Last array value overwrite when adding NSMutableArray into another NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsarray

```
    NSMutableArray *no1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *no2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
            NSString *no_str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j];
            [no1 addObject:no_str];
        }
        [no2 addObject:no1];
        [no1 removeAllObjects];
    }
    NSLog(@"Final:%@",no2);
```

I got output like:

Final:(
        (
        0,
        1,
        2
    ),
        (
        0,
        1,
        2
    ),
        (
        0,
        1,
        2
    )
)

But i need output like this:

Final:(
        (
        0
    ),
        (
        0,
        1
    ),
        (
        0,
        1,
        2
    )
)

Please any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I assume you are using ARC, so this code will work good.

```
NSMutableArray *no1;
NSMutableArray *no2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    no1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        NSString *no_str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j];
        [no1 addObject:no_str];
    }
    [no2 addObject:no1];
}
NSLog(@"Final:%@",no2);
```

EDIT: even if you alloc init the no1 the result will be same.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:-

```
NSMutableArray *no1;

    NSMutableArray *no2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        no1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (int j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
            NSString *no_str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j];
            [no1 addObject:no_str];
        }
        [no2 addObject:no1];
        [no1 release];
    }
    NSLog(@"Final:%@",no2);
```